# How can I assign a Struct Type value using a map?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go, struct

I want to create a multidimensional array as below:

```
[string][int] = Struct
```

I wrote the following codeblock. When I try to assign a Struct type to map, I get the following error:

> cannot use event (type *models.Event) as type map[int]models.Event in assignment go

Here comes the code block:

```
//Get func
func (c *EventController) Get() {
    days := [7]string{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}

    m := make(map[string][]map[int]models.Event)

    for _, day := range days {
        var i = 0
        o := orm.NewOrm()
        qs := o.QueryTable("events")
        qs.OrderBy("id")
        qs.Filter("days__name", day)

        var events []*models.Event
        num, err := o.QueryTable("events").RelatedSel().All(&events)

        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("%d events read\n", num)

            for _, event := range events {
                m[day][i] = event
                i++
            }
        } else {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }

    c.Data["json"] = m

    // c.TplName = "events.tpl"
    c.ServeJSON()
}
```

What is wrong in here?

Comment: It looks like `m` should be `map[string][]*models.Event`. You should also either append to the slices, or assign the entire slice: `m[day] = events`. It's hard to tell if this is the intended data structure or not from your code though.

Comment: It works as you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marc defined, I updated the codeblock as below. Now it works perfect!

```html
//Get func
func (c *EventController) Get() {

 days := [7]string{"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"}

 m := make(map[string][]*models.Event)

 for _, day := range days {
  o := orm.NewOrm()

  var events []*models.Event
  num, err := o.QueryTable("events").Filter("day__name__exact", day).RelatedSel().All(&events)

  fmt.Print("Day: ", day, " Count:", num, "\n")

  if err != nil {
   fmt.Printf("%d posts read\n", num)
  }

  m[day] = events
 }

 c.Data["json"] = m

 // c.TplName = "events.tpl"
 c.ServeJSON()
}
```